# 15.04 USB Camera connection detection stopped working

Tags: kubuntu, camera

After an upgrade to Kubuntu 15.04, now camera not detected as an attached device

(same bug as in as 13.04?). FujiFinepix camera

lsusb : Bus 001 Device 013: ID 04cb:01e8 Fuji Photo Film Co., Ltd

Comment: I opened Dolphin, then pasted camera:   Then I was able to open the camera, it is only a half fix, as device notification still isn't working.

Comment: how do you line break, markdown doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing with my Fuji X10. Even under devices the camera didn't show.

Going to Dolphin an type in "camera:" in the url bar. This way it is able to access the camera. At least this offers a way to access your pictures, although be it not automatic.

It seems to be related to this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1310303

Answer (score 0):

Automatic access to "camera:" has failed with 15.04 and dolphin

This is now "the procedure" to get at photo's

sudo apt-get install gphotofs
mkdir camera
gphotofs  ~/camera

then : point dolphin or cd to ~/camera directory,
copy photo's to "real" directory

Comment: thx, solved my problem on kubuntu 15.10